# How to update pkg-config in cent os?

Tags: apache, centos, mesos, mesosphere

I am trying to install mesos on centos. But during installation I get the following error when I run ./configure:

checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
./configure: line 19168: syntax error near unexpected token `google.protobuf,'
./configure: line 19168:`      AC_PYTHON_MODULE(google.protobuf, yes)'

The solution as mentioned here
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-1727 is to update the pig-config and retry.

Need help to understand how to update pkg-config.

Answer (score 1):

You fail to mention the version and the arch of your OS. Technically, in Centos with base repo all you have to do is:

```
yum install pkgconfig
```

Hope this helps,

Deeh

Comment: What If I wanted a higher version than the one given by the yum install command , 
or a specific version ?